# QT slot get Signaled twice

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals-slots, qtablewidget

In QT4.5,

I use a QTableWidget, and I have connected the signal QTableWidget::itemClicked() to a custom slot like this:

```
connect(_table, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTableWidgetItem*)), item, SLOT(sloItemClicked(QTableWidgetItem*)));
```

I create such a connection for each row I add to the table.

The problem is that the slot sloItemClicked get called more than once, it seem that it get called X time where X is the number of row in my table.

But it is calling for the same row all the time. (QTableWidgetItem that I receive is the same).

This is a problem, because when the row is clicked, I delete it. So the next time it gets called, the QTableWidgetItem is no longer valid and it crash.

If I have only one row, everything works as expected..

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should only create the connection once since the signal is a signal on the *table* and not on an individual `QTableWidgetItem`. When emitted it will give you the `QTableWidgdetItem` that you clicked on as the argument.